# obtener un valor de un funcion en javascript y enviarla a php para hacer una consulta en mysql

Tags: php

Buen día, estoy haciendo un calendario en php que al precionar hacer click en un día del mes, me muestre en una ventana si en esa fecha hay algun dato guardado en mi base de datos. utilizo javascript para que me diga que dia se seleccionó pero no se como enviar ese valor a php para luego hacer la consulta, podría alguien orientarme por favor.

Agrego parte de mi código, el calendario funciona bien mi,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dias_x(dia)
{
    var a=1;
    var dia;
    for(a=1;a<32;a++)
    {
        if(dia==a)
        {
            alert("Eventos del dia: "+dia);
        }
    }
return dia;
}
</script>

 <?php
//include 'variable.php';
$dias=1;
//dibujamos las celdas por mes seleccionado
for($i=1;$i<=$cantidad_dias;$i++)
{
//si la semanana no empieza en domingo corremos celdas
    if ($i <= $saltear_casillas)
    {
        echo '<td>-</td>';  
    }
    else
    {
        $num_dia=$i-$saltear_casillas;
        if($num_dia==$diaActual)
        {
            echo "<td class='hoy' onclick='dias_x($num_dia)' bgcolor='#f7dc6f' id='diaActual' onmouseover='cambiacolor_over(this)' onmouseout='cambiacolor_out(this)'>$num_dia</td>";
            $val2="$num_dia";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td  class='dia' onclick='dias_x($num_dia)' id='otro_dia'onmouseover='cambiacolor_over(this)' onmouseout='cambiacolor_out(this)' >$num_dia</td>";
            $num_dia++;
        }   
    }
    if($i%7==0)
    {
        echo'</tr><tr>';
    }
}
//escribir las celdas vacias
for($i=1;$i<=$diferencia;$i++)
{
    echo '<td>-</td>';
}
// empiexa para el popup

include 'conexion.php';
$fecha1=$numero_anio.'-'.$numero_mes.'-'.$diaActual;
$currentDate = $numero_anio.'-'.$numero_mes.'-'.$dias;
$venNum=0;
$resultado=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT nombre FROM eventos");

$evenNum =mysqli_num_rows($resultado);//mostrar cuantos datos hay almacenados en mi bd
echo $evenNum," cantidad de registros en la bd";
echo "<br>";
echo "Fecha de hoy"." ".$fecha1; //fecha de hoy
echo "<br>";
echo $currentDate;

include 'cerrarconexion.php'; //cerramos la conexion

?>
```

Comment: Tendrías que valerte de Ajax. Funciona así explicado brevemente: recoges la fecha desde tu archivo actual, la mandas al servidor vía Ajax, indicando un archivo PHP donde se recibirá la fecha, se conectará a la base de datos, hará la consulta y te devolverá el resultado. En una parte de la petición Ajax llamada `done` recibirás la respuesta del servidor y podrás actualizar un contenedor del archivo desde donde lanzaste la petición indicando un mensaje o lo que sea según lo ocurrido en el servidor. [Revisa Ajax aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Comment: ok gracias por la orientacion

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas rapida que yo utilizo es utilizando jquery

y utilizando la función ajax de la siguiente maner

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
        var url = "datos_login.php";
        $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                     
           data: $("#formulario").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)             
           {
             $('#resp').html(data);               
           }
       });
    });
});
```

in el archivo php puedes recibirlo así.

```
<?php   
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contra  = $_POST['contrasena'];

    echo "tu usuario es: ".$usuario; 
    echo "contraseña es: ".$contrsena;
?>
```

ya puedes hacer lo que quieras con los datos en php.

quedo atento a cualquier duda.